# Invalid data table format: column #1 must be of type 'date,number,datetime

Tags: c#, json, charts, google-visualization

i am workning with google charts and i'am try to do timeline chart but i have this error(Invalid data table format: column #1 must be of type 'date,number,datetime) where i retrieve the data from my web service my data like(Name,StartDate,EndDate)

```
google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['timeline'] });
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(draw_Charts);
        function draw_Charts() {
            var options = {
                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                width: '100%',
                height: 400,
                title: '',
                titleTextStyle: {
                    fontSize: 20,
                },

                legend: { position: 'left', textStyle: { fontSize: '40%' } },
                colors: ['#4285F4', '#007E33', '#ffbb33']
            };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Project_Data.asmx/GetChartData",
                data: '{}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (r) {
                    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(r.d);
                    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline($("#timeline")[0]);
                    chart.draw(data, options);
                },
                failure: function (r) {
                        alert(r.status + " - " + r.statusText);
                    },
                    error: function (r) {
                        alert(r.status + " - " + r.statusText);
                    }
            });
        }
```

this my methode from my web service to retrieve data it's working fine and when calling this method get data like this example   "Nam1","2020-09-01","2020-09-30"

```
public List<object[]> GetChartData()
        {
            string query = @"My query";
            List<object[]> chartData = new List<object[]>();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True"))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (sdr.Read())
                        {

                            var date = DateTime.Parse(sdr[3].ToString()).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"); ;
                            var date2 = DateTime.Parse(sdr[4].ToString()).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

                            chartData.Add(new object[]
                            {
                                    sdr[0],date,date2

                            });
                        }
                        sdr.Close();
                    }
                    con.Close();
                    return chartData;
                }
            }
        }
```

please someone have any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

the error occurs because the date values are coming across as strings in the JSON.

```
"2020-09-01"
```

need to convert to actual date objects, before building the google data table.

```
new Date("2020-09-01");
```

you can use the following to convert the values for each row, replace...

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(r.d);
```

with...

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(r.d.map(function (row, rowIndex) {
  if (rowIndex === 0) {
    // column headings
    return row;
  } else {
    // column values
    return row.map(function (col, colIndex) {
      if (colIndex === 0) {
        // name column
        return col;
      } else {
        // date column
        return new Date(col);
      }
    });
  }
}));
```

see following working example...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['timeline']
}).then(function () {

  var options = {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    width: '100%',
    height: 400,
    title: '',
    titleTextStyle: {
        fontSize: 20,
    },
    legend: { position: 'left', textStyle: { fontSize: '40%' } },
    colors: ['#4285F4', '#007E33', '#ffbb33']
  };

  var r = {};
  r.d = [
    ["name","start","end"],
    ["Nam1","2020-09-01","2020-09-30"],
    ["Nam2","2020-09-14","2020-09-30"]
  ];

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(r.d.map(function (row, rowIndex) {
    if (rowIndex === 0) {
      // column headings
      return row;
    } else {
      // column values
      return row.map(function (col, colIndex) {
        if (colIndex === 0) {
          // name column
          return col;
        } else {
          // date column
          return new Date(col);
        }
      });
    }
  }));

  var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline($("#timeline")[0]);
  chart.draw(data, options);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="timeline"></div>
```

Comment: @WhitehHat Thank you, but also sometimes like example in gantt chart am converting thee date but not fixed and  my date like this "2020 , 09 , 01" and i am addin new Date("2020 , 09 , 01") Whithout any success :)

Comment: you should build the json using the following format --> [Format of the data table constructor](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam) -- then you can pass actual date values using --> [date string representation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes#dates-and-times-using-the-date-string-representation) -- `"Date(2020, 09, 01)"`